# How to group objects with the same property value in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, collections, hashmap

I have 3 JSON arrays which looks as below. The 3 arrays have error details for type `1`, `2` and `3`

```
const data1 =
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 1A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 9
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 1B",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 9
  },

];

const data2 = 
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
    "Error": "wrong data for 2A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 8
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 2B",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 3
  },

];

const data3 = 
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
    "Error": "wrong data for 3A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 1
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 3C",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 5
  },

];
```

I want to combine the 3 JSON arrays data1, data2, data3 and the final JSON object should look as below:

```
{
  "details1": {
   "9": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 1A"
   },
      "9": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 1B"
   }
},
  "details2": {
   "8": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 2A"
   },
      "3": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 2B"
   }
},
  "details3": {
   "1": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 3A"
   },
      "5": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 3B"
   }
}
}
```

Please note that `Error-1A` and `Error-1B` have the same count. Any two error types can have the same count.
I am using following function to loop over the array elements, turning each of them into an object property using the `SERVER_COUNT` property as the key.

```
let finalData = {
  details1: dataToDetails(data1),
  details2: dataToDetails(data2),
  details3: dataToDetails(data3)
};

function dataToDetails (data) {
  let result = {};
  data.forEach(({ErrorType, Error, SERVER_COUNT}) => result[SERVER_COUNT] = {ErrorType, Error});
  return result;
}
```

However, it is not displaying both `Error-1A` and `Error-1B`

How to modify the above function so as to group objects with the same `SERVER_COUNT` value?

Answer (score 1):

you are not saving both objects but replacing one by one instead of

```
    result[SERVER_COUNT] = {ErrorType, Error}
```

you should do something like

```
    //There you are get all the objects that are already in result object and add new object to them;
    result[SERVER_COUNT] = result[SERVER_COUNT] ? [...result[SERVER_COUNT], {ErrorType, Error}] : [{ErrorType, Error}]
```

And if there will be some objects with properties except Error and ErrorType, it's better to do like this

```
    ( { SERVER_COUNT, ...rest } ) => result[ SERVER_COUNT ] = result[ SERVER_COUNT ] ? [ ...result[ SERVER_COUNT ], rest ] : [ rest ]
```

With Map

```
With Map will be something like


function dataToDetails(data) {
    let result = new Map();
    
    data.sort( ( { SERVER_COUNT: a }, { SERVER_COUNT: b } ) => b - a )

    data.forEach(
        ({ SERVER_COUNT, ...rest }) =>
            result.set(SERVER_COUNT, result.has(SERVER_COUNT)
                ? result.get(SERVER_COUNT).concat([rest])
                : [rest]),
    );
    return result;
}
```

And with arrays like that

```
function dataToDetails(data) {
    let result = [];
    
    data.sort( ( { SERVER_COUNT: a }, { SERVER_COUNT: b } ) => b - a )

    data.forEach(
        ( { SERVER_COUNT, ...rest } ) => {
            const index = result.findIndex( ( [ server_count ] ) => SERVER_COUNT === server_count );
            
            if ( index === -1 ) {
                result.push( [ SERVER_COUNT, [ rest ] ] );
            } else {
                result[ index ][ 1 ].push( rest );
            }
        }
    );
    return result;
}
```

Use version you like. Differs just format of the response, so check it in console, also Maps have API not like plain objects, so you can read it on the internet.

Comment: thanks. How to get the output in reverse chronological order? For example for type `1`, `2` and `3` it should show the first show the errors with maximum value of `SERVER_COUNT`

Comment: Then better to use array or Map instead of object, because in object properties always sorted

Comment: With Map will be something like

Comment: Can you please modify your answer using array of Map? Many thanks!!

Comment: I am using the `Map` function which you have given above but it is returning null. Can you please check at your end?